# Why does this regex not match the second binary gap?

Tags: python, regex

Trying a solution for the problem listed [here](https://codility.com/programmers/task/binary_gap/) in python, I thought I'd try a nice little regex to capture the maximum "binary gap" (chains of zeroes in the binary representation of a number).

The function I wrote for the problem is below:

```
def solution(N):
    max_gap = 0
    binary_N = format(N, 'b')
    list = re.findall(r'1(0+)1', binary_N)

    for element in list:
        if len(element) > max_gap:
            max_gap = len(element)

    return max_gap
```

And it works pretty well. However... for some reason, it does not match the second set of zeroes in `10000010000000001` (binary representation of `66561`). The 9 zeroes don't appear in the list of matches so it must be a problem with the regex - but I can't see where it is as it matches every other example given!

Comment: I think you just need `list = re.findall(r'1(0+)', binary_N)`. No need to consume the right-hand side `1`.

Comment: According to the instructions about complexity, would your algorithm meet the requirements (expected worst-case time complexity is O(log(N)))?
I thought about using regex but then kept it simple not using any module. 1st question: Would using regex add or substract any points? Or does it depend on the examiner?
2nd question: I came up with this solution: http://pastebin.com/TNhx37JG How good or bad is it? If I had to guess, I would say the complexiy is O(N) (because I have to iterate through all bits), but I can't guess how would it be with O(log(N)). Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Well as tested, it does meet the requirements, although I'll admit it is bending the rules slightly by using regex... have you tried your solution on the codility website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same bit can't be included in two matches. Your regex matches a `1` followed by one or more `0`s and ends with another `1`. Once the first match has been found you are left with `0000000001` which doesn't start with a `1` so isn't matched by your regex.

As mentioned by @JoachimIsaksson, if you want to match both sets of 0s, you can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so that the final `1` is checked but isn't included in the match. `r'1(0+)(?=1)'`.

Comment: +1. As a bonus , you can use a lookahead in the regex to make it not match (and eliminate) the trailing one; `r'1(0+)(?=1)'`

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson, I've added that in.